# How can I make my lucene search "global" (i.e. for all groups) in liferay?

Tags: lucene, liferay

I use the following in a search container to find the projects in a given group:

```
SearchContext searchContext = SearchContextFactory.getInstance(request);
searchContext.setStart(searchContainer.getStart());
searchContext.setKeywords(keywords);
searchContext.setEnd(searchContainer.getEnd());

results = ProjectLocalServiceUtil.getSearchedProjects(searchContext); 
total = ProjectLocalServiceUtil.getSearchedProjectsCount(searchContext);
```

The methods getSearchedProjects translates from search results to a list of projects:

```
public List<Project> getSearchedProjects(SearchContext context) throws SearchException {
    Indexer indexer = IndexerRegistryUtil.getIndexer(Project.class);
    Hits results = indexer.search(context);
    List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.getDocs().length; i++) {
        com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Document doc = results.doc(i);
        long projectId=GetterUtil.getLong(doc.get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK));
        Project project = null;
        try {
            project = ProjectLocalServiceUtil.getProject(projectId);
            projects.add(project);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            continue;
        }
    }
    return projects;
}
```

The results are as I expect when the search portlet is placed in the group referenced in the group I set in my projectIndexer's doGetDocument method:

```
document.addKeyword(Field.GROUP_ID, groupId);
document.addKeyword(Field.SCOPE_GROUP_ID, groupId);
```

but I would like to use the portlet to search from another group.

I tried to set the list of groupIds in the portlet, using

```
searchContext.setGroupIds(new long[] {projectHolder.getGroupId()});
```

but I still don't get any results in the search.

Any pointers on how I can search 'across groups' ?

Alain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. In order for

```
searchContext.setGroupIds(new long[] {group1ID, group2Id});
```

to have an effect the searchContext should NOT have groupId as one of its attributes. 
SearchContextFactory adds GroupId in the attributes (see the extract below), so after the call to getInstance, you need to  remove groupId from the attributes :

```
SearchContext searchContext = SearchContextFactory.getInstance(request);
Map<String, Serializable> attributes = searchContext.getAttributes();
attributes.remove("groupId");
```

Hope this helps someone someday.
Alain

---

Below, the extract from SearchContextFactory.getInstance(HttpServletRequest request) that (I believe - didn't debug it) sets the groupId attribute from the parameters :

```
// Extract from SearchContextFactory.java
Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    String[] values = entry.getValue();
        if ((values != null) && (values.length > 0)) {
        if (values.length == 1) {
            attributes.put(name, values[0]);
        }
        else {
            attributes.put(name, values);
        }
    }
}
searchContext.setAttributes(attributes);
```